# very difficult extraction of information from a string in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

Hi I have a large pandas dataframe that contains the following information:

> 5%
>   4
>   2.1
>   4.000
>   0.100%
>   BuyType: 2%,SellType: 29%
>   SellType 24%, fee type 0.2%, Non-fee 2%
>   BuyType: NONE Sell Agent 3 buy agent 4
>   ...

that is, this column gives me some information about a percentage that I need to extract.

The first 5 rows are straightforward to understand, even if there is sometime the % and sometime not.

The last three are more tricky, however there is always the sequence

```
SOME CODE_ID - SOME NUMBER
```

Is there a way to extract this information in Pandas? Say to store the different percentages in the corresponding variables (here BuyType equals 2 in row 6 and NONE in the last one, etc).

Maybe one strategy is to get the full set of `CODE_ID (non numeric)`, and then pass this to some regex function. I have no idea how to do that.

the output should be:

```
one  buytype  selltype  feetype  nonfee  sellagent  buyagent
5  0  0  0  0  0
4 0 0 0 0 0
2.1 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 
0.1 0 0 0 0 0
0 2 29 0 0 0 
0 0 0 24 0.2 2 0
0 NONE 0 0 0 3 4
```

Any suggestion is welcome
Many thanks!!!

Comment: What is your expecting output dataframe with your input data?

Comment: @jezrael Hi please see my edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution, but it was very complicated and in data cannot be char `|`, because I used it for splitting:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import re

temp=u"""5%
4
2.1
4.000
0.100% BuyType: 2%,SellType: 29%
SellType 24%, fee type 0.2%, Non-fee 2%
BuyType: NONE Sell Agent 3 buy agent 4"""

#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="|", header=None, names=['s'])
print df

def f(x):
    return re.sub(r"([\d\.]+|NONE)%?", r"\1|", ''.join(x)).rstrip('|')

#function - info http://stackoverflow.com/q/34857379/2901002 
df['s1'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)

#remove , : - arbitary whitespace(\s+)
df['s1'] = df['s1'].str.replace(r'[-,:\s+]', '').str.lower()
print df
                                         s                                s1
0                                       5%                                 5
1                                        4                                 4
2                                      2.1                               2.1
3                                    4.000                             4.000
4         0.100% BuyType: 2%,SellType: 29%         0.100|buytype2|selltype29
5  SellType 24%, fee type 0.2%, Non-fee 2%     selltype24|feetype0.2|nonfee2
6   BuyType: NONE Sell Agent 3 buy agent 4  buytypenone|sellagent3|buyagent4
```

```
#split data by | to new df
df = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('|') for x in df['s1'].tolist() ])

#stack data to 2 columns
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=0)
df.columns = ['id','data']

#extract number
df['number'] = df['data'].str.replace(r'[a-z]', '')
#extract none
df.loc[df.data.str[-4:].str.contains('none'), 'number'] = 'NONE'

#extract text
df['text'] = df['data'].str.replace(r'\d*\.\d+|\d+', '')

#add text to empty values of column text
df.loc[df['text'].str.len() == 0, 'text'] = 'one' 
#remove none
df.loc[df.data.str[-4:].str.contains('none'), 'text'] = 
df.loc[df.data.str[-4:].str.contains('none'), 'text'].str[:-4]
```

```
print df

   id         data number       text
0   0            5      5        one
0   1            4      4        one
0   2          2.1    2.1        one
0   3        4.000  4.000        one
0   4        0.100  0.100        one
1   4     buytype2      2    buytype
2   4   selltype29     29   selltype
0   5   selltype24     24   selltype
1   5   feetype0.2    0.2    feetype
2   5      nonfee2      2     nonfee
0   6  buytypenone   NONE    buytype
1   6   sellagent3      3  sellagent
2   6    buyagent4      4   buyagent

print df.pivot(index='id', columns='text', values='number').fillna(0)

text buyagent buytype feetype nonfee    one sellagent selltype
id                                                            
0           0       0       0      0      5         0        0
1           0       0       0      0      4         0        0
2           0       0       0      0    2.1         0        0
3           0       0       0      0  4.000         0        0
4           0       2       0      0  0.100         0       29
5           0       0     0.2      2      0         0       24
6           4    NONE       0      0      0         3        0
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael. Pure mastery

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! And you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34857379/2901002) and you can upvote this question too. thanks.