# Insert char to string to end of number

Tags: python, regex, string, insert, separator

I have ugly string:

```
oldstr = "0.100% fDrg: 2%,dgdv: 29% fGd dg 0.2%, Ghh-sf 2.2 dbgh: NONE dfgdf6 gd 3 "
```

I **need** to insert char `|` after the last digit of number for next splitting by this inserted `|`. There is also value `none`, where is also added this separator:

```
0.100| fdrg: 2|,dgdv: 29| fgd dg 0.2|, ghh-sf 2.2|dbgh: none| dfgdf6|gd 3|
```

I **try** this, but no success:

```
print re.sub(r'(\d+[a-z %^.])', r'\1|', oldstr.lower())

0.|100%| fdrg: 2%|,dgdv: 29%| fgd dg 0.|2%|, ghh-sf 2.|2 |dbgh: none dfgdf6 |gd 3 |
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The worst is that you seem to try to trim the value that comes after an integer. Do you really need that? Also, I see no easy way to turn the `none` to lowercase. Check [`(\bnone\b|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%?`](https://regex101.com/r/hZ8yN7/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
(\bnone\b|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%?
```

And replace with `\1|`.

*Explanation*:

- `(\bnone\b|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1 matching 2 alternatives:

  - `\bnone\b` - whole word `none`
  - `|` - or...
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - a float value (`\d+` matches one or more digits, and `(?:\.\d+)?` matches (optionally) a dot followed with one or more digits)
- `%?` - an optional (since `?` means *match one or zero times*) `%` symbol

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZ8yN7/1)

Python code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\bnone\b|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%?', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = "0.100% fDrg: 2%,dgdv: 29% fGd dg 0.2%, Ghh-sf 2.2 dbgh: NONE dfgdf6 gd 3 "
subst = "\1|"
result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

If you need to trim the values, you will be able to do it after splitting. Also, `none` can be turned lower case before processing the text with `re.sub(r'\b\none\b', 'NONE', input)`.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
>>> re.sub(r"([\d\.]+|NONE)%?", r"\1|", oldstr)
'0.100| fDrg: 2|,dgdv: 29| fGd dg 0.2|, Ghh-sf 2.2| dbgh: NONE| dfgdf6| gd 3| '
```

Here we are capturing one or more occurences of digits and dots or a `NONE` in a [capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) (followed by an optional `%` sign) and replacing it with itself and a pipe character.

Note that [@Wiktor's capturing part of the regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34857675/771848) is much better than in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
oldstr = "0.100% fDrg: 2%,dgdv: 29% fGd dg 0.2%, Ghh-sf 2.2 dbgh: NONE dfgdf6 gd 3"

newstring = re.sub(r"([\.\d]+)", r"\1|", oldstr)
print newstring.replace("%","").replace("NONE","NONE|")
```

output:

```
0.100| fDrg: 2|,dgdv: 29| fGd dg 0.2|, Ghh-sf 2.2| dbgh: NONE| dfgdf6| gd 3|
```

After a little more thinking here is a one-liner:

```
print re.sub(r"([\.\d'NONE']+)%?", r"\1|", oldstr)
```